# $f_n(x)=n(f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x))$ converges uniformly to derivative

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity

> Let $f$ be a continuous function with continuous derivative on $(a,b)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$.
>
> Define $f_n(x)=n(f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x))$.
>
> Prove that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f'$ on any interval $[c,d]\subseteq(a,b)$.

My proof:

Let $\epsilon>0$.

Since $f'$ is continuous on $[c,d]$ it is uniformly continuous, thus there is $\delta>0$ s.t. $|f'(x)-f'(y)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$.

By MVT,  $f_n(x)=n(f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x))=f'(t)$ for some $t\in(x,x+\frac{1}{n})$.

Choose $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{N}<\delta$. Then $\forall n\ge N$, we have:

$\sup\limits_{x\in[c,d]}|f_n(x)-f'(x)|=\sup\limits_{x\in[c,d]}|f'(t)-f'(x)|<\epsilon$, by uniform continuity, so done.

---

Can anyone please check if my proof above is correct? Thank you.

Comment: Note that your last quantity cannot make sense, as there is no reference to $t$.

Comment: If the main purpose of your question is to check this specific proof and ask about possible improvements, possible mistakes, criticism, etc. (as opposed to ask about any proof of the claim), you should use the ([tag:proof-verification]) tag - just to indicate this more clearly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is one small problem in your proof. We can't be sure that the point $t$ is still in $[c,d]$. For example in you take $x=d$ then $x+\frac{1}{n}$ will always be outside of the interval $[c,d]$, hence $t$ will be outside of the interval as well. And outside the interval you can't be sure the same $\delta$ works. And even if we forget about the point $x=d$ itself, other points still cause problems: if you take $x$ which is just a bit smaller than $d$ then you might need a very large $n$ to make sure that $x+\frac{1}{n}\in [c,d]$. And when points depend on $n$ it is a problem, because you need uniform convergence here.

Anyway, there is a simple way to fix the problem: find a big enough $M$ such that $d+\frac{1}{M}<b$, and then choose $\delta$ by uniform continuity in the interval $[c,d+\frac{1}{M}]$. From this moment it will be fine, because for each $n>M$ and for each $x\in [c,d]$ we indeed have $x+\frac{1}{n}\in [c,d+\frac{1}{M}]$. In this case all the points $t$ will indeed satisfy $|f'(t)-f'(x)|<\epsilon$ because $\delta$ works everywhere in $[c,d+\frac{1}{M}]$ while you take values of $x$ only from $[c,d]$.

Comment: Very nice, thank you!